# MATLAB Finding z_value of point on meshgrid

Tags: matlab

I'm plotting something using pcolor in Matlab. I am using the code pcolor(X,Y,Z), where X and Y are 2-D matrices of equal size to Z.

My question is that, given a value of X and Y, how can I find the value of Z at this point. For example, the value of Z when X = 10.32 and Y = -12.5. I know how to find the location in the the X and Y matrices where these values occur, but I'm not sure how get the Z value from this.

I should mention that the Z matrix isn't simply an analytical function of X and Y, rather I was just given value of Z and their corresponding X and Y points.

EDIT:
X and Y are NOT monotonically increasing.

The values of X and Y that I want to find Z at will always be present in the original X and Y matrices. For example, I want to find the value of Z corresponding to the X value at X(10,20) and Y value at Y(15,25).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`interp2` is your friend here.

The syntax goes (from docs): `Vq = interp2(X,Y,V,Xq,Yq)` , where `XYV` are your available data and `Xq` and `Yq` are the points whre you want your new `Z` values.

See the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html) for more information.

Comment: I get the following error: "Input grid is not a valid MESHGRID."  I lied before...X and Y were not created with meshgrid, rather they are Cartesian-converted grids from a meshgrid of polar coordinate data (see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/contour-plot-in-polar-coordinates.html) ). Point being that they are not monotonically increasing.

I should also mention that the 'Xq' and 'Yq' values I want will always be values present in the original X and Y matricies. So example, I want to find the value of Z corresponding to the X value at X(10,20) and Y value at Y(15,25).

Comment: @hm8 You should still be able to manage to play with `interp2`, however, if the values of X and Y are EXACTLY known, why not use `find`?

Comment: I can use "find" to get the indices in X and Y where the value I want is, but I can't find the corresponding Z-value to these X and Y points. How do I get the Z value that goes with X(r,c) and Y(r,c)?

Comment: the r,c value is different for X and Y.

Comment: @hm8 And Z? How is Z stored? Where are the Z located? in which X,Y? It totally looks like you are asking how to access the values of some data which you are the only one that knows how is stored!